# Is it possible to use Asyncio with win32com in Python?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pywin32

My python program receives data via Windows COM objects record it into an hdf5 file. In order to use the COM objects, I have used `win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents`. The code below shows the simplified structure of my program.

```
class Handler_realTime(object):  
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def OnReceiveRealData(self, eventTime, eventData01, eventData02, eventData03):
        m.target_table.append( np.array([( eventTime, eventData01, eventData02, eventData03 )] )
        m.file.flush()        # <--- being delayed due to IO processing!



class MainClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = tb.open_file('hdf5File.h5', 'a')
        self.target_table = self.file.root.realTime

        self.realReceving = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("Session.RealTime",Handler_realTime)
        # calls Handler_realTime whenever new data arrives

m = MainClass()
```

It works fine, but I have recently felt the low-performance of the program, due to its frequent `flush()` and excessive calls. Then, I thought that `Asyncio` might improve the performance, by randomly flushing the file and processing other tasks at the same time.

I have looked up some books on Asyncio in Python, but I couldn't find any examples that use classes instead of funcsions(async def). In other words, I don't know if it's possible to use functions(not classes) with `DispatchWithEvents` or if it's possible to adopt Asyncio in this situation.

Comment: It's not `win32com`  I'm worried about here. The HDF5 library doesn't support asynchronous operations.

Comment: So the best you can do is to push all such operations into a thread. That's something asyncio can help with, by using a thread executor, but if nothing else in your code uses asyncio there is not much point really.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Thank you for your answer. Do you mean that it's not possible to flush the file using ```run_in_executor(https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_in_executor)```? If it's not possible, I wonder how multithreading will make the performance better...

Comment: Yes, you can use `run_in_executor` to do that. That'll use the thread executor. You could also create a thread for that operation directly. `run_in_executor` is great for integrating non-async code into an async project, but if you don't have any coroutines in your codebase that may not be the easiest path.

Comment: If your code is slow because you're flushing too often, have you tried simply reducing the frequency of flushing? For example instead of calling `m.file.flush()` every time, keep a counter and flush when `self.counter % 1000 == 0` or something to that effect. Another option is to run a separate thread that invokes `flush()` and sleeps for a second in a loop.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Thank you. Tha't why I'm trying to rewrite my code and I have encountered a problem. which is not being able to use ```DispatchWithEvents``` with a coroutine(async def) instead of a class. I don't really understand how win32com wroks, so I'd like to get some advice on it.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thank you for your comment. I think that will be better than the current design, but if it's possible, I'd still like to use Asyncio and optimize my code more than that. Moreover, I know it's not recommendable, but the hdf5 is read in real time, so it should be updated(flushed) quite freqently.

Comment: If you need to call `flush()` frequently, but not have the rest of the code wait for it, I would recommend doing it in a separate thread. You can of course use asyncio anyway, but be aware that it's single-threaded and that it won't automatically optimize your existing body of blocking code.

Comment: @user4815162342 I thought that even if I used multi-threads, the performance wouldn't be better due to GIL, is it not true?

Comment: Python releases the GIL around IO operations, so it is not a concern here.